# Java sequences print

Tags: java, sequences

How do i write simpla Java sequence in my editor (using notepad++)?

I am familiar with the basics but having trouble getting this one to print in my cmd.

`int a = 1; a = a + a; a = a + a; a = a + a; ...`

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show us what you did.

Comment: I would paste this into the body of a `main(String[])` method in an IDE, add System.out.println(a); and press `[Run]` Or you could just work it out as `8`

Comment: are you trying to print `2 4 8 16....` sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what your looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int startValue = 1;
    int numberOfAdditions = 10;
    int currentValue = startValue;
    for(int i = 0;i<numberOfAdditions;i++)
    {
        //do opperations here
         currentValue = currentValue+currentValue;
        //print out value
         System.out.println(currentValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want them all on the same line you can do  System.out.print(currentValue+" ");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int a = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_PRINTS ; i++) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a *= 2;
}
```

Or if you want to print until a certain value is reached:

```
int a = 1;
while (a <= MAX_VALUE) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a *= 2;
}
```

Comment: It's addition, not multiplication.  Otherwise, this seems pretty concise.

Comment: Sorry I might be missing something - what do you mean "its addition"? In the question, subsequent values of `a` are computed by taking `a` and adding it to itself, i.e. multiplying it by 2.